# Concat two .ts files gets audio out of sync

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to concat two .ts files using ffmpeg. The files look like

Part 0:

```
$ ffprobe -hide_banner part0.ts
Input #0, mpegts, from 'part0.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:25.02, start: 1.408000, bitrate: 76 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
  Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, unknown/bt709/iec61966-2-1, progressive), 1920x1080, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 32000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 3 kb/s
```

Part 1:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'part1.ts':
  Duration: 00:33:03.10, start: 1.408000, bitrate: 886 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
  Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1[0x101](und): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 32000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s
```

And concatenation is done using:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "concat:part0.ts|part1.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc bla.mp4
```

But the concatenated file always shows sync issues between audio and video. I have been using these to concatenate in the past without errors, but now it fails.

Details about my ffmpeg:

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version n6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 13.2.1 (GCC) 20230801
configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-amf --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-lto --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libjxl --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpl --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-vulkan
libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
```